# How to create html plots which dynamically adjust marker size when zooming

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, plotly-python, mpld3

I've created a `Python` script that generates a bar chart using `Matplotlib` and converts it into an interactive `HTML` graphic using `mpld3`. The chart displays average hashing times for different algorithms and string lengths. However, I'd like to enhance the user experience by **dynamically adjusting the dot size as I zoom in on the graphic** in the `HTML` document.

Here's part of the script:

```
import hashlib
import random
import string
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing
import os
from datetime import datetime
import mpld3

algorithms = ['sha1', 'sha256', 'sha3_256']
string_lengths = [10, 25, 50, 75, 100]
num_samples = 50000
random_seed = 42
random.seed(random_seed)
custom_colors = ['#1f77b4', '#FFD700', '#2ca02c']

def generate_random_string(length):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))

def hash_string(input_string, algorithm):
    hash_func = hashlib.new(algorithm)
    hash_func.update(input_string.encode())
    return hash_func.hexdigest()

def hash_and_measure_avg_time(args):
    algorithm, random_strings = args
    num_samples = len(random_strings)
    
    start_time = time.time_ns()
    
    [hash_string(s, algorithm) for s in random_strings]
    
    end_time = time.time_ns()

    total_time = end_time - start_time
    return total_time / num_samples

def main():
    for i in range(10):
        num_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        cpu_count = os.cpu_count()

        print(f"\nUsing {num_cpus} CPU cores for analysis")
        print(f"Number of CPU cores available: {cpu_count}")

        random_strings = {}
        for length in string_lengths:
            random_strings[length] = [generate_random_string(length) for _ in range(num_samples)]

        results = {}
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
        results_folder = f"results_{timestamp}"
        os.makedirs(results_folder, exist_ok=True)

        for algorithm in algorithms:
            results[algorithm] = {}

            print(f"\nTesting hashing algorithm: {algorithm}")
            with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cpus) as pool:
                args = [(algorithm, random_strings[length]) for length in string_lengths]
                results_list = pool.map(hash_and_measure_avg_time, args)

            for length, result in zip(string_lengths, results_list):
                results[algorithm][length] = result

            time.sleep(1)

        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
        for i, (algorithm, avg_times) in enumerate(results.items()):
            avg_times = [avg_times[length] for length in string_lengths]
            plt.plot(
                string_lengths,
                avg_times,
                marker='o',
                markersize=4,
                label=algorithm,
                color=custom_colors[i]
            )

        plt.title('Average Hashing Time vs. String Length')
        plt.xlabel('String Length')
        plt.ylabel('Average Hashing Time (ns)')
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(True)

        interactive_plot = mpld3.fig_to_html(plt.gcf())
        plot_filename = f"c_result_{timestamp}.html"
        with open(os.path.join(results_folder, plot_filename), 'w') as html_file:
            html_file.write(interactive_plot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\n----- Welcome to the Hashing Performance Benchmark -----")
    main()
```

As it currently stands, the chart displays dots representing the data points, but they remain the same size when zooming in or out in the **HTML** graphic. **I want to make the dot size change dynamically based on the zoom level so that when I zoom in, the dots appear smaller, and when I zoom out, they appear larger.**

It reaches a point where, if I zoom in enough, the marker stops reducing its size and stays 'gigantic.' Is there a way to change this and make it continue dynamically decreasing until the maximum zoom level?

#### Without Zoom

[image]

#### With Zoom

[image]

#### Max Zoom Level

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your primary issue, because the marker size is dynamically changing with zoom level. If I zoom in, the x and y range changes, and the markers increase in size. [Initial Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJUYI.png) and [Zoomed Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPWS3.png) with image open in Chrome. Markers should be larger when zooming in, and smaller when zooming out. If you need a larger starting marker, then increase `markersize=4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, Olla, as far as I know, the markers do not dynamically change their size when zooming in or out in the HTML graphic due to the limitations of the mpld3 library. I don't know if it would fit your project, but you could use the `Plotly` library instead of `matplotlib` and `mpld3`. This way, you could achieve dynamic marker size changes based on the zoom level and have it continue to decrease even with high zoom levels and lots of other functionalities.

```
import hashlib
import random
import string
import time
import multiprocessing
import os
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go

algorithms = ['sha1', 'sha256', 'sha3_256']
string_lengths = [1, 10, 25, 50, 75]
num_samples = 50000
random_seed = 42
random.seed(random_seed)
custom_colors = ['#1f77b4', '#FFD700', '#2ca02c']

def generate_random_string(length):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))

def hash_string(input_string, algorithm):
    hash_func = hashlib.new(algorithm)
    hash_func.update(input_string.encode())
    return hash_func.hexdigest()

def hash_and_measure_avg_time(args):
    algorithm, random_strings = args
    num_samples = len(random_strings)
    
    start_time = time.time_ns()
    
    [hash_string(s, algorithm) for s in random_strings]
    
    end_time = time.time_ns()

    total_time = end_time - start_time
    return total_time / num_samples

def main():
    for i in range(10):
        num_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        cpu_count = os.cpu_count()

        print(f"\nUsing {num_cpus} CPU cores for analysis")
        print(f"Number of CPU cores available: {cpu_count}")

        random_strings = {}
        for length in string_lengths:
            random_strings[length] = [generate_random_string(length) for _ in range(num_samples)]

        results = {}
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
        results_folder = f"results_{timestamp}"
        os.makedirs(results_folder, exist_ok=True)

        for algorithm in algorithms:
            results[algorithm] = {}

            print(f"\nTesting hashing algorithm: {algorithm}")
            with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cpus) as pool:
                args = [(algorithm, random_strings[length]) for length in string_lengths]
                results_list = pool.map(hash_and_measure_avg_time, args)

            for length, result in zip(string_lengths, results_list):
                results[algorithm][length] = result

            time.sleep(1)

        # Create a Plotly scatter plot
        fig = go.Figure()

        for algorithm in algorithms:
            avg_times = [results[algorithm][length] for length in string_lengths]
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=string_lengths, y=avg_times, mode='markers', name=algorithm, marker=dict(size=4, color=custom_colors[algorithms.index(algorithm)])))

        # Add lines between the dots
        for i in range(1, len(string_lengths)):
            for algorithm in algorithms:
                x = string_lengths
                y = [results[algorithm][length] for length in x]
                fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines', name=f'{algorithm} Lines', line=dict(color=custom_colors[algorithms.index(algorithm)], dash='dot')))
        
        # Customize the layout
        fig.update_layout(title='Average Hashing Time vs. String Length', xaxis_title='String Length', yaxis_title='Average Hashing Time (ns)', legend_title='Algorithm')
        fig.update_xaxes(type='log')

        # Save the interactive plot as an HTML file
        html_file = os.path.join(results_folder, f"c_result_{timestamp}.html")
        fig.write_html(html_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\n----- Welcome to the Hashing Performance Benchmark -----")
    main()
```

Comment: Wow, I mean it's not `mpld3`, and it still needs some fine-tuning, but it definitely fits my project. In a way, it's so much better than `mpld3` for data visualization. Thanks for the answer, and I'll definitely read more about this library!

Comment: Great! I'm glad that you liked it. 